# Changing namespace in PHP SoapClient request?

Tags: php, xml, soap, laravel-4

I am looking for a way to change the namespace: "ns1" into "ret", tested the below XML using SoapUI with the namespace set to "ret" and the request was successful. I've "googled", and searched the answers from other related questions here in SO, but no luck. So, I am kind of desperate to find the answer...

Here is the XML that is generated to be sent to request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://retailexpress.com.au/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:ClientHeader>
            <ns1:ClientID>Random-hash-clientID</ns1:ClientID>
            <ns1:UserName>Username</ns1:UserName>
            <ns1:Password>Password</ns1:Password>
        </ns1:ClientHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:CustomerGetBulkDetails>
            <ns1:LastUpdated>2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</ns1:LastUpdated>
            <ns1:OnlyCustomersWithEmails>1</ns1:OnlyCustomersWithEmails>
        </ns1:CustomerGetBulkDetails>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Though, it seems a bit odd that we have to request with the same namespace (ret), but that's how it is...

Here is the PHP code used to generate the above:

```
    $rexHost = '<domain of retail express>';
    $rexApi = '<URI of retail express API / wsdl path>';
    $rexUser = 'Username';
    $rexPassword = 'Password';
    $rexApiClient = 'Random-hash-clientID';
    $rexApiHost = 'http://retailexpress.com.au/';

    $client = new SoapClient($rexHost.$rexApi, array('trace' => true));

    $auth = new stdClass();
    $auth->ClientID = $rexApiClient;
    $auth->UserName = $rexUser;
    $auth->Password = $rexPassword;

    $header = new SoapHeader($rexApiHost, 'ClientHeader', $auth, false);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    $lastUpdate = '2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'; //hardcoded for test

    $params = array();
    $params[] = new SoapVar($lastUpdate, XSD_DATETIME, null, null, 'LastUpdated', $rexApiHost);
    $params[] = new SoapVar(1, XSD_INTEGER, null, null, 'OnlyCustomersWithEmails', $rexApiHost);

    try {
        $users = null;
        return $users = $client->CustomerGetBulkDetails( new SoapVar($params, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::info($e->getMessage());
        Log::info($client->__getLastRequest()); //laravel logger, where I got the generated SOAP XML request
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I can't find anything wrong in your code. Were you able to find the issue?

Comment: I never found how to changed the namespace. But, it seems to work now without having to change a single code. Probably, because we requested support and they manage to resolve the issue. The namespace "ns1" works now with our SOAP request to their API... Thanks!

Comment: Ah server problems :)

Answer (score 7):

`ns1` is not the namespace but an alias for it. `http://retailexpress.com.au/` is the namespace. The namespace definition `xmlns:ns1="http://retailexpress.com.au/"` defines an alias for the current element and its descendants. A namespace has to be unique and stable. Using a definition and aliases allows for complex URI used as an namespace and short, readable aliases for the serialization.

The following three examples are all resolved to and element `CustomerGetBulkDetails` in the namespace `http://retailexpress.com.au/` by an XML parser:

- `<ns1:CustomerGetBulkDetails xmlns:ns1="http://retailexpress.com.au/"/>`
- `<ret:CustomerGetBulkDetails xmlns:ret="http://retailexpress.com.au/"/>`
- `<CustomerGetBulkDetails xmlns="http://retailexpress.com.au/"/>`

In other words, if the XML/SOAP implementation work correctly it does not matter which alias - `ns1` or `ret` - is used for the namespace.

Comment: as long as the alias is consistent, across the whole XML?

Comment: Not even that, it is valid for the current element and all attribute/descendant nodes until it is redefined on a descendant element node. So yeah, you can have several aliases for one namespace or the same alias for several namespaces in a single XML document. Of course you should try to avoid it - it makes you XML more difficult to read for a human. But it allows to copy a fragment from another document into an existing one for example.